# How to publish posts depend on privacy?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, queue

I need to publish a queue from collection Posts depending of privacy. But I don't have any idea how to get this. I've draw mindmap of main concept what I try to realize:

[image]

**Input:**

```
var currentUser = "Andrey"; 

Events.find();
```

**Output:**

```
[
{
    //it's going to output, becouse I've created this post
    "_id" : "1",
    "createdBy" : "Andrey",
    "private" : true,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : [ 
        "Sheldon", "Mike"
    ]
},
{
    //it's going to output, becouse this post not private
    "_id" : "2",
    "createdBy" : "Sheldon",
    "private" : false,
    "title" : "",
    "members" : []
},
{
    //it's going to output, becouse I'm one of members'
    "_id" : "3",
    "createdBy" : "Mike",
    "private" : true,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : [ 
        "Andrey"
    ]
},
{
    //it's NOT going to output, becouse it's private post, I'm not the member or author
    "_id" : "4",
    "createdBy" : "Ana",
    "private" : true,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : [ 
         "Sheldon"
    ]
},
]
```

**Expected result:**

```
[
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "createdBy" : "Andrey",
    "private" : true,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : [ 
        "Sheldon", "Mike"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "createdBy" : "Sheldon",
    "private" : false,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : []
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "createdBy" : "Mike",
    "private" : true,
    "title" : "",
    "text": "",
    "members" : [ 
        "Andrey"
    ]
}
]
```

But this idea can be wrong at all, maybe you have another way?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the right approach but probably I'd try something like that if I face this issue. (By the way I'd use userId instead of names. If you used names in order to explain your aim, please ignore this comment)

As long as I remember, you can return multiple query results like that

```
return [
        Result1,
        Result2,
       ]
```

For the public posts, no need to worry I guess. Just returning the ones with `private: false` is sufficient.

For the private ones, I'd use userId as parameter and try this composite publication:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function postPublication(userId) {

  return [
    Posts.find({
    $and: [{
      $or: [
        {_id: userId},
        {memberId: {$in: userId}}
      ]},
      {private: {$eq: true}}
     ]}), // => should return private posts created or commented by member
    Posts.find({private: {$eq: false}}) // => should return public ones
  ];
}
```

Then do the subscription with userId

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts', userId);
```

Comment: Thanx, a lot! I think it has only one decision of this problem, is to do with $and $or statements, like in your example. I spend all day for experiments with it, and now I get expected result. And about user id, I'm using ids too, it's was given for example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code how I solved this task, with $or $and. But not sure too, if it's a best solution. But I get expected result.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(currentUser) {
selector = { 
                $or : [
                    { $and : [ {'private': true, 'members': currentUser} ] },
                    { $and : [ {'private': true, 'author': currentUser} ] },
                    { $and : [ {'private': false, 'author': currentUser} ] },
                    { $and : [ {'private': undefined} ] },
                    { $and : [ {'private': false} ] },

                ]
            }
 return Posts.find(selector);
});
```